# выпадающий список на js в yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2

Подскажите, нужно внедрить в yii2 такую реализацию:
два поля. тема и подтема, и есть соответсвующие связанные таблицы в БД.требуется чтобы при вводе или выборе из существующих темы, во втором поле выпадали соответствующие подтемы.честно даже не знаю с чего начать.есть идеи?буду рад любой помощи

Comment: Начинайте с событий изменения, потом смотрите AJAX, потом смотрите построение html из js.

Answer (score 1):

Для связанных списков есть замечательная библиотека DepDrop.

https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-depdrop

Демо: http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop#basic-usage